# How to convert a jpeg map of borders into a shapefile?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, convert, jpg

I have a map of French departments from the 19th century (impossible to find in shapefile format) in jpeg format and I would like to convert it into a shapefile in order to regroup raster data and compute averages by departments.

I know questions like this have already been posted but I am really new to QGIS and I do not understand the answers given to those questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the QGIS trainingsmanual there is a chapter about digitizing forestry-maps: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/stands_digitazing.html.

You can use the same method that is described there.